# symfony2 Multiple firewalls login_check”

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I build symfony2 project and i have 2 bundles one for admins and one for users .
i configured my security.yml so admins can login but users can't .

i have followed this tutoriel http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/book/security.html

this is my security.yml:

---

security:

```
encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12
        BackOfficeBundle\Entity\Administrateur:
             algorithm: bcrypt
        BackOfficeBundle\Entity\Collaborateur:
             algorithm: bcrypt


role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: BackOfficeBundle:Administrateur, property: username }
        users:
            entity: { class: BackOfficeBundle:Collaborateur, property: email }


firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        front_login:
            pattern:   ^/clogin$
            anonymous: true
        back_login:
            pattern:   ^/login$
            anonymous: true
        back:
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: false
            provider: administrators

            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
                default_target_path: /platform

            logout:
                path:   logout
                target: /login

        front:
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: false
            provider: users
            form_login:
                login_path: clogin
                check_path: clogin_check
                default_target_path: /collaborateur

            logout:
                path:   clogout
                target: /clogin


access_control:
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
     - { path: ^/platform, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
     - { path: ^/collaborateur, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

---

### my routing.yml:

front_office:

```
resource: "@FrontOfficeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /collaborateur
```

back_office:

```
resource: "@BackOfficeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /platform
```

login:

```
pattern:   /login
defaults:  { _controller: UserBundle:Security:login }
```

login_check:

```
pattern:   /login_check
```

logout:

```
pattern:   /logout
```

clogin:

```
pattern:   /clogin
defaults:  { _controller: UserBundle:Security:clogin }
```

clogin_check:

```
pattern:   /login_check
```

clogout:

```
pattern:   /logout
```

---

what's should i change in my code to permit users to login? 
should i have two login_check?

Comment: Okay? And what is the question?

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: you can't share the same url, as example try for clogin_check the pattern /clogin_check and for clogout: the pattern /clogout. hope this help

Comment: thank you @Matteo for your answer . login_check is defined by symfony i don't know to solve this problem

Comment: seems because you configure all your route behind both your firewall: frontend and backend pattern is ^/ so you must change the route of the backend as  `pattern:   ^/platform`

Comment: i changed as you said . now users can login but when i try to login as admin in "localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/login"; i enter my login and pass correctly and it redirect me to "localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/clogin"; .any solution?

Comment: try to set the farewall of the frontend to the `pattern: ^/collaborateur`

Comment: now it generate an exception for both "Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". The route is wrongly configured."  and "Unable to find the controller for path "/clogin_check". The route is wrongly configured."

Comment: you must move all the URL of the login(check..) route under the correct path, as example, for collavorateur, `collavorateur/login`, `collavorateur/login_check`etc and set the ACCESS_CONTROL directive to anomymous for the login route. Hope this help